# How to get reference to "instance methods" in ECMA6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to be able to serialize an object declared with a class in ECMA6 . I could use `toJSON` easily when using standard JavaScript to get and serialize the "methods" stored in the prototype.

```
var Foo = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Foo.prototype = { 
    doSomething: function() {
        return 1;
    },
    toJSON: function() {
        // construct a string accessing Foo.prototype
        // in order to get at functions etc. stored in prototype...
    }  
};
```

But how do I do this using class declarations in ECMA6? Example:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
    doSomething() {
        return 1;
    }   
    toJSON() {
        // Foo.prototype is empty. Because it hasn't been created yet?
    }
}
```

Even after instantiation with the `new` operator, objects created with `class` seem to have an empty prototype. What am I missing?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. It's not like you're a new user.

Comment: As an alternative to serialising the objects wholesale, you could just serialise all the data they need and then re-create them using the stored data.

Comment: If you need to stringify the methods, and then parse them back later, you're probably doing something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @vlaz, that would probably work. With the disadvantage obviously that I'd have to explicitly access the function name.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing sounds like a bad idea; but at any rate, class methods *are* in the prototype; they just are not enumerable, to avoid having them showing up in `for .. in` iteration (and also probably to prevent things like what you are trying to do from being easy to do). You would have to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`.

Comment: It may be a bad idea. I am doing it because PhantomJS only allows things that are JSON serializable to be passed in to `page.evaluate`. I have a module of test objects that get run on a page opened by PhantomJS and that need to get passed in to `evaluate` and deserialized once inside PhantomJS's `page.evaluate`s scope.

The idea behind sandboxing `page.evaluate` is to keep the scope of the page and the phantomjs script separate, but `page.evaluate` does allow passing in simple data, so they obviously found that there are valid use-cases.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. It returns an array of property names but seems to skip properties with functions as values.